# Joining Multiple dataframes using Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, left-join

I have following dataframes

```
df1 - df1_id, name, age
df2 - df2_id, df1_id, subject, marks
df3 - df3_id, df2_id, city, country
```

Result

```
dfResult = df1_id, name, age, df2_id, subject, marks, df3_id, city, country
```

Is this possible in Pyspark? I know I can use join to make df1 and df2 joined together

```
left_join = df1.join(df2, df1.df1_id == df2.df2_id,how='left')
```

But im not sure if I can join all three to get the expected output.

Comment: if you are unfamiliar with data frame register as temp tables nd join in the normall way u do df1.createOrReplaceTempView("table1") df2.createOrReplaceTempView("table2") df3.createOrReplaceTempView("table3") df4 = spark.sql("select a.* from table1 a left outer join table2 b on a.df1_id=b.df1_id left outer join table3 on b.df2_id=c.df2_id") df4.show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just chain the `join`:

```
df1.join(df2, ['df1_id'], how='left').join(df3, ['df2_id'], how='left')
```